# jquery unbind toggle event don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div element generate in runmode by javascript
I want first click show confirm message and next click remove click event
but die or unbind don't work!

```
$('div').live('click',function(e) {

    $(this).toggle(function () {
            $(this).html("I'm sure!");
            return false;
        },
        function (e) {

            $(this).html("Deleting...");
            $(this).die('click').die('click');

        }).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: note: `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead

Comment: @Topener: Only in version 1.7 and later is `live()` deprecated and `on()` to be used instead. In older versions pre 1.7 `.delegate()` is preferred over `.live()`

Comment: on don't work with element generate in runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?

```
$('div').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);

    if (el.data("confirm")) {
        el.html("Deleting").off("click");
    } else {
        el.html("I'm sure!").data("confirm", true);
    }
});​
```

​
**EDIT.** Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/93nPA/

**EDIT 2.**
If you wish the script to add click event to the generated elements automatically, just add the class to the generated element (e.g. `mybutton`), and use this code *once* in the very top of your JavaScript: `$("body").on("click", "div.mybutton", function(e) { ... });`.

Comment: @StefanoCudini, please check the post update and try EDIT 2 section if you need automatic event-attaching.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating the handler callback in a separate function like this

```
var Div_Click = function(e) {
    // code for this handler
};
```

so it's easy to bind and unbind

```
$("div").bind("click", Div_Click); // or "live" or "on"
$("div").unbind("click", Div_Click);
```

Comment: Taken from the jQuery unbind documentation http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.)

Comment: As you mention live in the comments beside your code. Taken from jQuery documentation on live: http://api.jquery.com/live/ As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: Thanks bro, but I'm not too concerned about the actual code. This was pretty much to suggest the OP to have the callback in a separate function. More as a concept than implementation

Comment: tnk! i try in this mode but however bind work and unbind dont work! i don't understund becase!!?

var deldiv = function(e) {

    $(this).toggle(function () {
            $(this).html("I'm sure!");
            return false;
        },
        function (e) {

            $(this).html("Deleting...");
            $(this).die('click', deldiv);

        }).trigger('click');
}

$('div').live('click',deldiv);

Comment: I'm resolve in this mode:

 results$.delegate('.del', 'click', function (e) {
  switch($(this).data('stat'))
  {
   case undefined:
    $(this).data('stat','sure').html("<em>I'm sure!</em>");
   break;
   case 'sure':
    $(this).data('stat','del').html("<em>Deleting...</em>");
    //do delete call in ajax...
   break;
   case 'del':
    return false;
  }
 });